# Counting field occurrences

Tags: awk

How can I count unique strings from multiple columns and display their count with only `awk`

My input file `c.txt`:

```
US A one
IN A two
US B one
LK C one
US B two
US A three
IN A three
US B one
LK C two
US B three
US A one
IN A one
US B three
LK C three
US B two
US A two
IN A two
US B two
LK C three
US B two
US A one
IN A two
US B one
LK C one
US B two
US A three
IN A three
US B one
LK C two
US B three
US A one
IN A one
US B three
LK C three
US B two
US A two
IN A two
US B two
LK C three
US B two
US A one
IN A two
US B one
LK C one
US B two
US A three
IN A three
US B one
LK C two
US B three
US A one
IN A one
US B three
LK C three
US B two
US A two
IN A two
US B two
LK C three
US B two
US A one
IN A two
US B one
LK C one
US B two
US A three
IN A three
US B one
LK C two
US B three
US A one
IN A one
US B three
LK C three
US B two
US A two
IN A two
US B two
LK C three
US B two
US A one
IN A two
US B one
LK C one
US B two
US A three
IN A three
US B one
LK C two
US B three
US A one
IN A one
US B three
LK C three
US B two
US A two
IN A two
US B two
LK C three
US B two
```

I was able to achieve this but separately with 3 commands, is that possible to get all the output with single command

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for (i in a)print i,a[i]}' c.txt
awk '{a[$1" "$2]++}END{for (i in a)print i,a[i]}' c.txt
awk '{a[$1" "$2" "$3]++}END{for (i in a)print i,a[i]}' c.txt
```

My desired output should be:

```
IN 20 A 20 one 5 
IN 20 A 20 three 5
IN 20 A 20 two 10
LK 20 C 20 one 5
LK 20 C 20 three 10
LK 20 C 20 two 5
US 60 A 20 one 10
US 60 A 20 three 5
US 60 A 20 two 5
US 60 B 40 one 10
US 60 B 40 three 10
US 60 B 40 two 20
```

The 2nd column is total uniq values of 1st column of input file.

The 4th column is total uniq values of 1st and  2nd column of input file.

The 6th column is total uniq values of 1st, 2nd and 3rd column of input file.

Comment: Please, make your example on a smaller sample of data. We do not want to scroll down.

Comment: Well done on giving an example input and output and posting what you have already tried along with what you expected to happen. You will find this formatting guide helpful when posting future questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 3):

With `GNU awk` you can use the following script:

```
$ cat count.awk 
{
    lines[$0]=$0
    count1[$1]++
    count2[$1,$2]++
    count3[$1,$2,$3]++
}
END{
    n = asorti(lines)
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        split(lines[i],field,FS)
        total1 = count1[field[1]]
        total2 = count2[field[1],field[2]]
        total3 = count3[field[1],field[2],field[3]]

        print field[1],total1,field[2],total2,field[3],total3
    }
}
```

To run the script on your file:

```
$ awk -f count.awk file 
IN 20 A 20 one 5
IN 20 A 20 three 5
IN 20 A 20 two 10
LK 20 C 20 one 5
LK 20 C 20 three 10
LK 20 C 20 two 5
US 60 A 20 one 10
US 60 A 20 three 5
US 60 A 20 two 5
US 60 B 40 one 10
US 60 B 40 three 10
US 60 B 40 two 20
```

Comment: If you notice the desired output, the last three lines have `B 20` instead of `B 40`. probably an error in the question.

Comment: I have already edited the question to remove this error. The OP describes what the output column should be so it's safe to assume it's a mistake, also your answer gives the same output which reassures I didn't make a simple mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Try this awk one liner:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]++;b[$1,$2]++;c[$1,$2,$3]++}END{for (i in c) {split (i, d, SUBSEP); print d[1],a[d[1]],d[2],b[d[1],d[2]],d[3],c[d[1],d[2],d[3]] } }' file | sort
IN 20 A 20 one 5
IN 20 A 20 three 5
IN 20 A 20 two 10
LK 20 C 20 one 5
LK 20 C 20 three 10
LK 20 C 20 two 5
US 60 A 20 one 10
US 60 A 20 three 5
US 60 A 20 two 5
US 60 B 40 one 10
US 60 B 40 three 10
US 60 B 40 two 20
```

Or in a more readable format:

```
$ awk '
    {
        a[$1]++
        b[$1,$2]++
        c[$1,$2,$3]++
    }
    END{
        for (i in c) {
            split (i, d, SUBSEP); 
            print d[1], a[d[1]],
                  d[2], b[d[1], d[2]],
                  d[3], c[d[1], d[2], d[3]] 
        } 
    }' file | sort
```